# Retrofitting ES6 modules to an existing TypeScript project

Tags: javascript, module, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a TypeScript project that I started a year ago when tooling/language/libraries were at a stage that choosing a module system was confusing and risky - so I chose none.

I used `tsd` to pull in the `.d.ts` files for external libraries and compiler was happy. I used - occasionally - `/// <reference src=""` for my own files and nothing else (no module system).

I let TypeScript compiler create a single output JavaScript file which I referenced from a Web page, preceded by references to the external libraries (in the order of dependency).

Everything worked fine.

I am now switching to ES6 modules transpiled (by TypeScript) to CommonJS. I am also not referencing the dependencies in the Web page which hosts my JavaScript result, but will be using `browserify` to bundle everything together.

Finally, the question: how do I make sure that **in compile time** the TypeScript compiler warns about missing `import` statements which reference external code?

In the current code, since I use `tsd` (soon `typings`) all the declaration files are included in the source tree, compiler sees them and is happy. However, nothing is `require`d in the output (I have yet to add `import` statements for external code) and if I don't include the dependency in the final HTML myself (which I don't want to do anymore, I want `browserify` to bundle everything for me), the code won't work, plus I have to run it to see that it doesn't work (whole point of TypeScript is to catch as many errors as I can while compiling and not while running the code).

When I do use `import` syntax, the compilation works and the `require` is emitted in the JavaScript, but **only** if TypeScript definition file is present (I kind of expected the compiler to look into `node_modules`, though since only JavaScript is there I guess it cannot really know which symbols have been exported).

In order for compiler to tell me where I need to add `import` for external code, I tried removing typings produced by `tsd`, which does produce errors for all places where I'm referencing the external dependencies, but if I keep typings removed, I cannot compile any more (not without errors).

I know this sounds like "have cake and eat it too" scenario, but I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious.

What would be the best approach to this, if any? Or should I continue with my "remove typings, blindly type `import` wherever there are compilation errors, then put back typings and pray that things work in runtime"?